# Change default JRE in debian Wheezy

Tags: java, debian

I am installing library libapache-mime4j-java in debian Wheezy. However, this depends on the default JRE which is Java 1.6 and therefore installs Java 1.6 by default. Is there any way to change the default JRE to Java 1.7 when installing a package that depends on it using

```
apt-get install libapache-mime4j-java
```

so that after installing the library you end up with Java 1.7 instead of Java 1.6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no. The [default-jre on wheezy points to openjdk-6-jre for amd64](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/default-jre).

BUT you can also install `openjdk-7-jre`, and select the former using [`update-alternatives` facility](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) or `update-java-alternatives` from `java-common` package.